# Bluetooth earphones do not autoconnect on MacOS

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, ear-phones

I have a macbook pro with MacOS Catalina, and a pair of Xiaomi Mi Air 2 SE earphones.

I don't have problems to pair them, and I can listen it well.

But the problem is with the autoconnect. When I open the lid of the earphones case, The earphones appear "connected" in the bluetooth devices panel, but they didn't appear in the sound devices list (like they are not connected).

After 5 seconds, the earphones appear "disconnected" again in the bluetooth devices list, and now I can select them, click "connect", and then they work fine.

I would like to just open them and have them connected automatically, like is supposed to work.

I don't think is a earphones problem, because they work fine in an android device, with autoconnect. (I have unpaired them from the phone before trying in the macbook, is the only device that they are paired, so the problem is not that they pair with another device)

Thank you!

Comment: The exact same thing happens to me with a Bose Soundlink Mini and I have never found a solution for it.